# Codimension in the completion

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Y\subset X$ be a subspace of codimension 1. Let $\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(Y)$ be the closure of $Y$ in the completion $\widehat{X}$ of $X$. Is still the dimension of $\widehat{X}/\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(Y)$ equal to one?

Comment: No. Your subspace $Y$ can be dense in $X$, and in this case you have $\overline Y=\widehat X$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any [non-zero discontinuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional) on $X$, say $f$. Then $\operatorname{Ker}(f)$ [is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135791/the-kernel-of-a-continuous-linear-operator-is-a-closed-subspace) in $X$. It is remains to put $Y=\operatorname{Ker}(f)$, so we have $\operatorname{cl}_{X}(Y)=X$. Since $\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(X)=\widehat{X}$ by construction of completion, then 
$$
\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(Y)=\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(Y))=\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(X)=\widehat{X}
$$
and we conclude $\operatorname{dim}(\widehat{X}/\operatorname{cl}_{\widehat{X}}(Y))=0$.