# Why is this unbounded linear functional also has a closed kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis

On the space $l_0$ of sequences with finite non-zeros, define $f:l_0\to l_0$ to be:
$$f(x)_k=kx_k,$$
then $f$ is famously unbounded. According to my textbook, that means $f$ must have a non-closed kernel. But in this particular case, isn't it that the kernel of $f$ is $\{0\}$, which is clearly closed?

Comment: The kernel is necessarily non-closed only for a linear *functional*. A discontinuous linear operator can have a closed kernel.

Comment: A little bit more general: the implication "kernel closed $\Rightarrow$ continuity" holds true only if the target space is finite dimensional (see, e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135791/the-kernel-of-a-continuous-linear-operator-is-a-closed-subspace).

Comment: @Romeo: Yeah, your right, I forgot it has to be finite dimensional. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: It should be "you're", sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given in comments: because it's not a linear functional, but a linear operator with infinite-dimensional range. An important class of unbounded operators is [closed unbounded operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators); they have closed graph, and consequently, closed kernel. Thus, the given example is far from being exceptional.