# Existence of a dense hyperspace

Tags: functional-analysis

How do you prove that every infinite dimensional normed space contains a dense hyperspace? (Where hyperspace is defined to be maximal proper subspace.)

Comment: Use the existence of an infinite basis to construct an unbounded linear functional. The kernel will be dense (why?)

Comment: @PhoemueX: I suggest you post your answer as an answer, and not as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using (e.g.) Zorn's Lemma, one can show that each vector space has a basis. So choose a basis $(x_i)_i$.

As your space $X$ is infinite-dimensional, there is an infinite sequence $(i_n)_n$ (consisting of distinct elements). We can assume $\Vert x_i\Vert = 1$ for all $i$.  Now define a functional $\varphi$ by

$$
\varphi(x_{i_n}) = n \text{ and } \varphi(x_i) =0 \text{ for } i \notin \{i_n\mid n \}. 
$$

This implies that $\varphi$ is an unbounded linear functional, hence discontinuous.

Now [If a linear functional is not bounded, then it has a non-closed kernel.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603314/if-a-linear-functional-is-not-bounded-then-it-has-a-non-closed-kernel) shows that the kernel of $\varphi$ is a non-closed (hence dense) hyperspace in $X$. It is maximal because of $\Bbb{K} = \varphi(X) \cong X/\text{ker}(\varphi)$.