# Proving that a linear operator $T$ is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

If the space $X$ is banach , then I want to show that any linear map $T:X \to X$ is continuous iff the null space is closed. I could show that if $T$ is continuous then the null space is closed. But I am unable to prove the converse. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "I want to show that any continuous map $T:X→X$ is continuous iff the null space is closed". Did you mean "linear map"?

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä yes I meant linear map I have made that correction

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603314/if-a-linear-functional-is-not-bounded-then-it-has-a-non-closed-kernel) might be a full solution to your problem?

Comment: I disagree. You don't even have unbounded operators in the case of a finite-dimensional space so the answer would not make any sense. 

In fact, it also generalizes far beyond Banach spaces (to topological vector spaces).

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä sorry for my sloppiness but what I actually meant was if $T:X \to Y$ is a linear operator and $Y$ is finite dimensional then I can show that $T$ is continuous iff null space is closed. But notice that for proving this i do not need to assume it is a Banach Space. Here what I am asking is quite more than just for functionals whereas the above link which you provided only works for functionals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true. See the $T$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/426494/58577). Since this $T$ is injective, its kernel is $\{0\}$.

Note that a similar assertion is true for linear functionals $T : X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JohnMa I had not realised that mistake initially that is why I accepted your answer. Now I have accepted this answer

Answer (score 1):

This is not the solution of your problem but its a interesting result in case of $f$ is linear functional.

Here is a sketch of more general result.Try to fill the gaps in the proof.

**Lemma:** Let $f$ be a linear functional on $X$ .A hyperplane $H= \{ x\in X : f(x) = \alpha\}$ is closed iff $f$ is continuous.

**Proof:** Clearly if $f$ is continuous then $H$ is closed.Conversely,Assume $H$ is closed therefore $H^c$ is open and since $f$ is nonzero its nonempty.(Why?)

WLOG,assume that $x_0 \in H^c$ is such that $f(x_0) < \alpha$.Since $H^c$ is open there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x_0,2r) \subset H^c$.Now for all $x \in B(x_0,2r)$,we have $f(x) < \alpha$ (Why?)

Thus for any $z \in V$ such that  $\|z\| \leq 1$,we get $f(x_0 +rz) \leq \alpha$ or equivalently $$ f(z) \leq \frac { \alpha -f(x_0)}{r}$$.Thus the image of the unit ball is bounded and hence $f$  is bounded (Why?) therefore continuous.

Comment: This proof does not generalize to $T : X \to X$.

Comment: agree,thats why I've assumed $T$ to be linear functional.

Comment: @Arpit Kansal actually i knew this result but I was wondering if I could generalise this

Comment: okay,I'm gonna delete this answer.

Comment: @ArpitKansal I do not think it is necesary to  delete this well written answer It might me of some help to another person